# Have a way to convert files in .isx to .dsx?

Tags: sonarqube, datastage

I'm new with IBM InfoSphere DataStage, I have a job to use SonarQube to validate .dsx files. But I'm receive to validate both, .isx and .dsx files. The plugin that I'm using, from Phydya, only validates .dsx files.

Comment: After a better understood, I see that .isx is only a "zipped" file. The output file .bin uses DSEXECJOB, and the another file .pjb (Parallel Job) have a XML code, I can use XMLStarlet to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. As you mentioned in your comment, you can use XMLStarlet